# Remove special characters except Hyphen and Space in Oracle String Data

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, formatting

I need to remove all the special characters except Hyphen and Space in Oracle String Data using Reg_replace function.Please help. For ex:

> **Input**-> `My Name is #name1`  **Output** -> `My Name is name1`
>
> **Input**-> `this is my add-ress#"` **Output**-> `this is my add-ress`
>
> **Input**-> `can  we remov-e this';` **Output**->`can  we remov-e this`

Comment: You can use a regular expression, but you need to define exactly what you want to remove - or probably more simply, what you want to keep. e.g. all alphanumeric characters plus dash and space? What about periods and commas? etc.

Comment: How fast does it need to be? (That depends on two things: how much data must be processed, and how often.) A regular expression solution is easy to write or maintain. Alternatively, you can write a solution with the faster function `translate`, but it will be uglier.

Comment: @Alex: yes, I want to keep all alphanumeric plus dash and space . Everything else needs to be removed ( even commas periods need to be removed).

Comment: @mathguy: around 100k records. And yes, I am trying to use reg_exp function reg_replace but not able to figure out exact syntax for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following

```
with t(str) as
(
 select 'this is my add-ress#&%! : 198' from dual
)
select regexp_replace(str,'[^-0-9A-Za-z ]','') as "Result String"
  from t;

Result String
-----------------------
this is my add-ress  198
```

Comment: Thanks , this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[^[:alnum:] -]` as a regular expression to match the values you want to replace.

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test_data( value ) AS
  SELECT 'this is my add-ress#\' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'My Name is #name1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'can we remov-e this' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT value,
       REGEXP_REPLACE( value, '[^[:alnum:] -]', NULL ) AS replaced_value
FROM   test_data
```

**Output**:

```
VALUE                 | REPLACED_VALUE     
:-------------------- | :------------------
this is my add-ress#\ | this is my add-ress
My Name is #name1     | My Name is name1   
can we remov-e this   | can we remov-e this
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=88f28feb7ca344042fa225e6986c21d2)*